# Clicking two buttons simultaneously does not work

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have two div on which ng-click is applied.As the button is clicked click count is incremented.I want the user to click both the buttons simultaneously,when clicked at the same time the count is not incremented.In some cases on one buttons count is incremented.

below is the click code that is run on ionic app(i.e mobile phone)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.clickCountA = function (clicks) {
        $scope.Aclicks = clicks;
        console.log("a ka value=" + clicks);
   }
   $scope.clickCountB = function (clicks) {
       $scope.Bclicks = clicks;
       console.log("b ka value=" + clicks);
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn success" ng-click="a=a+1;clickCountA(a)">click Me a</button>
    <button class="btn btn success" ng-click="b=b+1;clickCountB(b)">click Me b</button>
    <br/>
    a count:{{a}}<br/>
    b count:{{b}}
</div>
```

I want when the user clicks on both the buttons simultaneously both the count should be incremented.Is there any code in angularjs/ionic which can achieve this

Comment: what is your exact requirement?? It will not possible to click both button at the same time with the same user

Comment: two buttons clicked by same user at the same time and onclick(ng-click)incrementing thier values

Comment: I'm guessing that you're occasionally triggering another gesture, hence why simultaneous clicks aren't always registered. You may want to use touch events instead (which support multitouch).

Comment: can you specify a bit more